# Graduate Studies Scholarship Application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

I am working on a scholarship application, and am worried the achievement section is a little sparse. It asks:
ACHIEVEMENTS: SUMMARIZE IN CV STYLE - AWARDS, PAPERS PRESENTED AT MEETINGS/CONFERENCES, PAPERS SUBMITTED FOR
PUBLICATION, PAPERS PUBLISHED, INVOLVEMENT IN ACADEMIC LIFE (MENTORING/TEACHING, INVOLVEMENT IN STUDENT GOVERNMENT,
COMMITTEES, TEAMS, PROFESSIONAL SOCIETIES, ORGANIZING CONFERENCES OR MEETINGS), AND PERSONAL ACHIEVEMENT (FOR EXAMPLE:
RECOGNIZED ATHLETIC, ARTISTIC OR ENTREPRENEURIAL ACHIEVEMENT)

I have 2 undergrad scholarships, dean's list, and a GPA award as well as a paper that was presented at a conference, but I really wasn't involved much on campus. I was thinking to add a few professional training certifications I've receive in the 3 years since undergrad, as well as a brief blurb about my time in the workforce (promotions, significant achievements, etc). I'm hesitant about adding some of my high school achievements though as it has been a nearly 8 years since graduating, but I was pretty involved in extracurricular and adding them would likely make me seem more well rounded.

So thoughts? Are the professional and high school achievements worth mentioning or are they superfluous and more likely to hurt my chances?

Comment: The ALL CAPS hurts my eyes and will likely turn off many possible answerers. Might want to edit that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Professional achievements -- so long as they are relevant to the program you are applying to -- are great to add:

- Successfully managed a major project in XYZ? That means you've got good communication skills, good leadership skills, and you know XYZ to boot!
- Obtained certificates in ABC and DEF? Here's someone who values their education!
- Got promoted 3 times in 2 years? Ambition, perseverance, dedication -- all good traits in a graduate student.

High school achievements, on the other hand, are probably not worth including. As you noted, it's been almost a decade (sorry). Moreover, your professional life is likely a far better indicator of who you are as a person than your high school life.

FWIW, the paper presented at a conference as an undergrad is also a very strong selling point.